# Flex RegEx to find string not starting with a pattern

Tags: regex, string, flex-lexer

I'm writing a lexer to scan a modified version of an INI file.

I need to recognize the declaration of variables, comments and strings (between double quotes) to be assigned to a variable. For example, this is correct:

```
# this is a comment
var1 = "string value"
```

I've successfully managed to recognize these tokens forcing the `#` at the begging of the comment regular expression and `"` at the end of the string regular expression, but I don't want to do this because later on, using Bison, the tokens I get are exactly `# this is a comment` and `"string value"`. Instead I want `this is a comment` (without `#`) and `string value` (without `"`)

These are the regular expressions that I currently use:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    { return TOKEN_VAR_NAME; }
["][^\n\r]*["]          { return TOKEN_STRING;   }
[#][^\n\r]*             { return TOKEN_COMMENT;  }
```

Obviously there can be any number of white spaces, as well as tabs, inside the string, the comment and between the variable name and the `=`.

How could I achieve the result I want?

---

Maybe it will be easier if I show you a complete example of a correct input file and also the grammar rules I use with Flex and Bison.

Correct input file example:

```
[section1]
var1 = "string value"
var2 = "var1 = text"
# this is a comment
# var5 = "some text" this is also a valid comment
```

These are the regular expressions for the lexer:

```
"["                     { return TOKEN::SECTION_START; } 
"]"                     { return TOKEN::SECTION_END; }
"="                     { return TOKEN::ASSIGNMENT; }
[#][^\n\r]*             { return TOKEN::COMMENT; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    { *m_yylval = yytext; return TOKEN::ID; }
["][^\n\r]*["]          { *m_yylval = yytext; return TOKEN::STRING; }
```

And these are the syntax rules:

```
input   : input line
        | line
        ;

line    : section
        | value
        | comment
        ;

section : SECTION_START ID SECTION_END      { createNewSection($2); }
        ;

value   : ID ASSIGNMENT STRING              { addStringValue($1, $3); }
        ;

comment : COMMENT                           { addComment($1); }
        ;
```

Comment: Seems with a lexer you have to parse every character. I don't know if it is viable to use lookaround assertions. So, you may have to maintain a state of _STRING\_START_ (and end) using `["]` and _COMMENT\_START_ using `[#]`. Also, to get the contents of the simple string (that knows nothing of escaped quotes) you would use `[^"]*` to span lines (i.e., not `[^\n\r]*`)

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to treat `"` and `#` as different tokens (so they get scanned as individual tokens, different from the one you are scanning now) and use a `%s` or `%x` start condition to change the accepted regular patterns on reading those tokens with the scanner input.

This adds another drawback, that is, you will receive `#` as an individual token before the comment and `"` before and after the string contents, and you'll have to cope with that in your grammar.  This will complicate your grammar and the scanner, so I have to discourage you to follow this approach.

There is a better solution, by writting a routine to unescape things and allow the scanner to be simpler by returning all the input string in `yytext` and simply

```
m_yylval = unescapeString(yytext);  /* drop the " chars */  
return STRING;
```

or

```
m_yylval = uncomment(yytext); /* drop the # at the beginning */
return COMMENT;  /* return EOL if you are trying the exmample at the end */
```

in the `yylex();` function.

## Note

As comments are normally ignored, the best thing is to ignore using a rule like:

```
"#".*         ; /* ignored */
```

in your `flex` file.  This makes generated scanner not return and ignore the token just read.

## Note 2

You probably don't have taken into account that your parser will allow you to introduce lines on the form:

```
var = "data"
```

in front of any

```
[section]
```

line, so you'll run into trouble trying to `addStringvalue(...);` when no section has been created.  One possible solution is to modify your grammar to separate file in sections and force them to begin with a section line, like:

```
compilation: file comments ;

file: file section
    | ; /* empty */

section: section_header section_body;

section_header: comments `[` ident `]` EOL

section_body: section_body comments assignment
    | ; /* empty */

comments: comments COMMENT
    | ; /* empty */
```

This has complicated by the fact that you want to process the comments.  If you were to ignore them (with using `;` in the flex scanner) The grammar would be:

```
file: empty_lines file section
    | ; /* empty */

empty_lines: empty_lines EOL
    | ; /* empty */

section: header body ;

header: '[' IDENT ']' EOL ;

body: body assignment
    | ; /* empty */

assignment: IDENT '=' strings EOL
    | EOL ; /* empty lines or lines with comments */

strings: 
      strings unit
    | unit ;

unit: STRING
    | IDENT
    | NUMBER ;
```

This way the first thing allowed in your file is, apart of comments, that are ignored and blank space (`EOL`s are not considered blank space as we cannot ignore them, they terminate lines)